# "group by is used to organize the data before other clauses - such as where, order by and functions...",really? Ref: Learning MySQLupdate

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause, clause

"group by is used to organize the data before other clauses - such as where, order by and functions -are applied. In contrast, order by is applied last- after the query has been resolved -to reorganize the query output for display.",really? Ref: Learning MySQL

I have surfed the net regarding this but couldn't find anything like this.
Is this an error in book?

---

update:
I just notices alias works in group by which means it is getting executed after select,
since select is executed after where , can we safely say that it was an error with the book and group by is executed after where clause?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: What makes you think it is an error? give more context, you'll get better answers.

Comment: i have googled but nothing says group by is executed first ... is there a way to confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Better explanation is here
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm

Comment: thanks Madhivanan for the link but i am confused with this order because group by supports alias so it is definitely executed after select
(   1. FROM clause
   2. WHERE clause
   3. GROUP BY clause
   4. HAVING clause
   5. SELECT clause
   6. ORDER BY clause )